# Eclipse Window Activates (and moves window to active linux workspace) when Debugger Breakpoint Hit

Tags: linux, eclipse, debugging

When running and debugging server side code with Eclipse, and you activate a breakpoint being hit by visiting a url, posting data, etc.  Eclipse window will automatically activate over top of your current window.

Not only that, but if your focus is in another workspace, Eclipse gets moved to that workspace as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Preferences
2. Run / Debug
3. Uncheck `Activate workbench when a breakpoint is hit`